# Hide option Generate automatic URL alias for all languages on user register form?

Tags: path-aliases

Do I need to write a hook or may be I can hide this using amdin interface?
I am using Pathauto i18n, LoggingToBoggan.
The option "Generate automatic URL alias for all languages" is displaying on user register form, and my users can't understand why. I want to hide it only on register form
this code is not correct and does not work:

```
function my_user_register_form_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  /* hide Generate URL alias for all languages */
  if (isset($form['pathauto_i18n_status'])) $form['pathauto_i18n_status']['und']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your hook is correct? Try a generic `hook_form_alter()` and `dpm($form_id)` to make sure.  Or just `die('yep')` in your hook.

Comment: the name of my module is: my_user_register_form. I've tried to add field like in field api docs "I agree terms.." and it displayed. so the name is correct. but the comand is not correct now

Comment: Is `['und']` supposed to be there?

Comment: i tried both with and without und

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to hide it or set the option's `#access` value to false using a custom module.  The first will hide it but leave it available to be ticked, the second will completely remove it from the page.

Comment: thank you. this do not work for me: function my_user_register_form_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  /* hide Generate URL alias for all languages */
  if (isset($form['pathauto_i18n_status'])) $form['pathauto_i18n_status']['und']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
how to write a code?

Comment: Too hard to read in a comment mate, if you've chosen to go that way, edit your question or ask a new one.